# Saves only .temp extension file while uploading .pdf file in laravel through ajax formData request

Tags: laravel, file, pdf, upload

I am uploading multiple files(pdf and images) through ajax request appended in formData.
images is uploading fine (using image/intervention package).
But the problem is, uploading pdf is not working properly. Currently a folder named with pdf file is created and inside that folder, a .temp extension file is saved.
[image: Folder with filename.pdf]

[image: file inside above folder with filename.temp]

And here is my code for saving pdf file.

```
public function savePdfFile($full_path, $file_category, $pdfFile){
        //check directory and make if doesnot exist
        if(!is_dir($full_path)){
            mkdir($full_path, 0777, true);
        }

        $filename = $file_category.'-'.time().'-'.md5(rand()).'.'.strtolower($pdfFile->getClientOriginalExtension());
        $pdfFile->move($full_path.$filename);
        return $filename;
    }
```

Comment: I guess you are sending wrong value to `savePdfFile`? debug value of `$full_path`

Comment: Try `$pdfFile->store($full_path.$filename);` instead

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, for the silly mistake.
I used full stop (.) instead of comma (,).
the correction is:

```
$pdfFile->move($full_path,$filename);
```